# Degree of projective curve related to its reduction

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

Let $X$ be an irreducible closed subscheme of dimension $1$ of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ for some $n$. Let $X'$ be the closed reduced subscheme associated to it, which is an integral projective curve. Definining the degree of $X$ as the top degree coefficient of its Hilbert polynomial, I think that one should get an equality $deg(X)=m deg(X')$ where $m$ should be the length of $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$ , being $\eta$ the generic point of $X$.

I've tried to write down the exact sequences relating $\mathcal{O}_X$ and $\mathcal{O}_X'$ but I did not get anything really useful.

Comment: Is your $X’ = X_{red}$? If so, then it follows from the associativity formula for Hilbert-Samuel multiplicity.

Comment: Yes it is but I do not know anything about such a formula